# Cloudlfare subdomain with www does not work

Tags: dns, subdomain, cloudflare, cname

I want to use cloudflare to get the following scenario working:

```
www.mydomainname.de -> CNAME to -> myapp.herokuapp.com
mydomainname.de -> CNAME to -> myapp.herokuapp.com

help.mydomainname.de -> CNAME to -> websitebuilder.whatever.de
www.help.mydomainname.de -> CNAME to -> websitebuilder.whatever.de
```

Everything is working except the last one. www.help.mydomainname.de does not resolve. I tried it with a redirect page rule but this does not work.

My Page rules are:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean “does not resolve” ? it should work. Also, how can you use a CNAME for naked domain mydomainname.de ? That shouldn’t be allowed

Comment: Its called CNAME Flattening. www.help.mydomain.de does not resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add another DNS-Entry: `CNAME www.home.`

After this `www.home.example.com` resolves.